# Fixed Row With Grouping in Mind?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have this data which i want to create a report using a SSRS

[image: Original]

The document column is grouped by customer column.
However there's conditions for the report 
- Every 10 Rows the report should trigger a page break.
- If the record less than 10, then empty row will be generated until 10 rows then page break trigger.
- If the record more than 10, then only first 10 will be displayed then the rest is on next page.

Here's the sample of result for page 1, page 2, and page 3:

[image: Result]

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new row group "Parent" , click on the group properties, and on the group expressions enter the expression: =Floor((RowNumber(Nothing)-1) / 10)

go to the next tab down, page breaks and click on between each instance of a group.